# Run Two Kubernetes Dashboards Simultaneously

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

Is it possible to run two Kubernetes dashboard's locally within two different shells? I want to view two different cluster's at the same time, however, I run into an issue with the dashboard's port.

1. Open Dashboard on 1st cluster
2. Open new shell and switch context to 2nd cluster
3. Open Dashboard on 2nd cluster

I created the first dashboard like so:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')
$ kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

I opened a new shell and changed context to the new cluster receiving the error:

```
$ listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8001: bind: address already in use
```

I understand *why* this is happening, however I'm not sure how to mitigate this problem.

Furthermore, when I change the port to 8002 for the second cluster's dashboard I'm unable to view both pages live without one rendering an `Internal Server Error (500): square/go-jose: error in cryptographic primitive`

I have switched to incognito, adding a Chrome configuration to erase/ignore browser cookies from localhost:8001 and localhost:8002, however when I go to login I receive the following error in the Chrome console:

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {  
"data":"MSG_LOGIN_UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR\n",
"status":401,
"config":{  
  "method":"GET",
  "transformRequest":[  
     null
  ],
  "transformResponse":[  
     null
  ],
  "jsonpCallbackParam":"callback",
  "url":"api/v1/rbac/status",
  "headers":{  
     "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"
  }
},
  "statusText":"Unauthorized",
  "xhrStatus":"complete",
  "resource":{  

  }
}
```

Comment: You can use different port

Answer (score 5):

The problem originates from the kubectl-proxy. The first one is using port 8001 and a port can be used only once.
You can start your second kubectl on a different port

```
kubectl proxy --port=8002
```

You need to point your browser to the different port to access the other dashboard, of course.

Comment: I'm able to render the 2nd dashboard website, however when I sign in with a newly generated token, the other cluster's dashboard receives a Internal Server Error (500) error: `square/go-jose: error in cryptographic primitive.` I have tried using incognito to prevent issues with browser cookies, but I still get the same error.